# What is the SQL “Distinct” equivalent in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I’m new to Kibana and Elasticsearch. I have a field name called `serviceprovidername`. I would like to find how many distinct service provider name present in this field. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have tried so far.

> search query

```
GET _search{“ages”: {“distinct_serviceprovidername”:{“terms”:{“field” :”serviceprovidername”}}}}
```

If my raw data is like this

```
 Serviceprovidername 
 _______________________
          X
          Y
          X
          Y
          Y
          Z
```

I’m excepting result as:

```
    Serviceprovidername 
    _______________________
             X
             Y
             Z
```

Comment: Do you need a visualization, browse them or just to see the count number?

Comment: I want to see the names, NOT count.Please note that I can see this from discover however the list of names are so huge that checking one by one consuming lost of time ( also I may miss something).I tried this from visualisation matrix browser however unable to see this, not sure if something wrong I am doing. My goal is to see the distinct names , it could be by whatever means, I am OK.Thanks.

Comment: Their is easy way to check distinct values in visualization in kibana. y-axis : count , field name and x-axis : term , in data you can check your distinct values with counts.

Comment: @Nusrath I tried that, what does y axis count means? Also, how to do wild card search If I found names in a short form? May be using a regular expression?Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn’t find a “distinct “ kind of things in Kibana. However I’m able to plot this on x-y axis as suggested.Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The following "terms aggregation" should work if you could run it on Kibana > DevTools > Console:

```
GET /_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "distinct_serviceprovidername" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "serviceprovidername" }
        }
    }
}
```

The query returns a multi-bucket value source including distinct values of `serviceprovidername` field like this:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 15601,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "distinct_serviceprovidername" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 67,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "X",
          "doc_count" : 301
        },
        {
          "key" : "Y",
          "doc_count" : 207
        },
        {
          "key" : "Z",
          "doc_count" : 175
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: `"size": 0` is used when aggregations are required but search hits are not. In this occasion, fetching search hits does not make any sense, so I ignored it to make the request more efficient by returning only aggregation results.

Comment: I’m getting the “buckets” : []. Any idea why? Am I not searching in correct bucket? Is there any way to find out the buckets? Also, what does “size” means here?

Comment: Another observation, it’s saying illegal argument exception. Field data is disabled on text field by default.set field data as true on serviceprovidername.Altrnatively use keyword field instead. However, when I’m making field data as true after the serviceprovidername, it’s again saying illegal argument exception reason is [terms] unknown field [fielddata], parser not found. “Status “ 400. Any clue please?

Comment: It seems to me that "serviceprovidername" field searchable but not aggregatable. If you try to sort, aggregate, or access values from a script on a such field, you will see that exception. 

Solution: would you use "serviceprovidername.keyword" field instead of "serviceprovidername" on the same script and share the result with me.

Comment: I also added information about why I used "size": 0 on the script.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked perfectly with wild card search and regex in it.

This is how my data looks `Tags:All Docs,Domains,ToAnalyse,Unique`

I applied filters on Tags columns and get unique count.

Below is my query:

```
GET test1/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "7772": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "Unique": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "Tags:Unique",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "default_field": "*"
            }
          },
          "ToAnalyse": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "Tags:To.*",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "default_field": "*"
            }
          },
          "All Docs": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "Tags:All Docs",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "default_field": "*"
            }
          },
          "Outdated": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "Tags:Outdated",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "default_field": "*"
            }
          },
          "Domains": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "Tags:Domains",
              "analyze_wildcard": true,
              "default_field": "*"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  }
}
```

And my output :

```
{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 152636,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "7772" : {
      "buckets" : {
        "All Docs" : {
          "doc_count" : 152636
        },
        "Domains" : {
          "doc_count" : 43374
        },
        "Outdated" : {
          "doc_count" : 24322
        },
        "ToAnalyse" : {
          "doc_count" : 128260
        },
        "Unique" : {
          "doc_count" : 152636
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)